# How to parse a "whereis" output to get a needed path in Linux?

Tags: bash, awk

Anyone has a bash or awk one-liner to parse the output of this command?

```
# whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java
```

so it returns, in this case, the path `/usr/local/openjdk-8`? IOW, what is `some_script`?

```
# whereis java | some_script
/usr/local/openjdk-8
```

I know at least to do this, but now to just get `/usr/local/openjdk-8`

```
# whereis java | awk '{print($3)}'
/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java
```

**Update/edit per Charles Duffy's suggestion**

Using this command

```
# type -P -a java
/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java
```

How can I pipe it to get this? IOW, what is `some_script`?

```
# type -P -a java | some_script
/usr/local/openjdk-8
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use specifically `whereis` for this purpose, instead of the POSIX-specified alternative tool for the same job?

Comment: The other thing is that there are _two_ paths returned, the first one is `/usr/bin/java`. If you want it to be ignored, it would be a good place to start in figuring out _why_ you want it to be ignored. Should specifically only `/usr/bin` be ignored? Should the second result always be the one used?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes I have a reason, and yes I want the second path.

Comment: Really? So taking the second line of `type -P -a java` wouldn't do? (That one isn't POSIX-specified, but it _is_ bash-builtin, which `whereis` isn't).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oh I see now. I'll will use that instead. Now how can I pipe `type -P -a java` to get just `/usr/local/openjdk-8`

Comment: BTW, on your current operating system, is `/usr/bin/java` a symlink to `/usr/local/openjdk-9/bin/java`, or is it an OS-vendor-provided script that does an alternatives lookup or similar?

Comment: I assume your goal is to find the correct value for JAVA_HOME, and in general, there are better ways to do it; what those better ways are depends on large part on your operating system vendor -- if they provide an alternatives system (to allow configuration of which of several packages provide the same command should be used), the Right Thing is to use it.

Comment: (Also, how your JVM is packaged matters -- if the package comes from your OS vendor it'll almost certainly _use_ that alternatives system correctly; if it's a 3rd-party or in-house package it may not; so figuring out what The Right Thing is can mean getting into the details a bit -- but that's better than making _assumptions_ about those details and having them break next time you install a JVM update).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, no I'm not wanting the correct value for JAVA_HOME, i can get that. That's why I asked a very specific question.

Comment: `echo /usr/local/openjdk-*`?

Comment: @Cyrus what if the next installation is not in /usr/local? It just happened to be in this case for the Docker base image I'm using.

Comment: How do you know the next installation or the next base image will even have anything other than `/usr/bin` in the `PATH` at all? I'd call that a much larger concern (indeed, most distros _don't_ put your actual JVM install location in the PATH, as the code requested here assumes will happen).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`whereis` is not POSIX-standardized, and also not part of bash itself. As such, it's a particularly poorly-chosen tool for the job.

I would strongly suggest using the shell-builtin `type` command. If your goal is to find the top-level directory for the 2nd copy of `java` found during a `PATH` lookup, then:

```
{ read _; read -r java_loc; } < <(type -P -a java)
echo "Java was found at $java_loc"
```

Once you've got that, stripping off the `/bin/java` is a simple parameter expansion (as `${var%suffix}` refers to everything in `var` before `suffix`):

```
{ read _; read -r java_loc; } < <(type -P -a java)
java_parent_loc=${java_loc%/bin/java}
echo "Java was found under ${java_parent_loc}"
```

That said, I do not by any means recommend this as a way to set your `JAVA_HOME` -- it's very unnecessarily fragile, making assumptions about your `PATH` order that are not guaranteed to be well-founded.

Comment: thanks, this is not a one-liner anymore though. How would I pipe the `type` command to get what I need?

Comment: Replace the newlines with `;`s, and bam, one-liner.

Comment: (I generally frown on any efforts to prioritize terseness over clarity and explicit code, especially in bash -- the language is [full of pitfalls and caveats](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls), and it's easy to overlook correctness and performance concerns when going for code that's short above all else).

Comment: thanks. So I did `{ read _; read -r java_loc; } < <(type -P -a java); java_parent_loc=${java_loc%/bin/java}; echo "Java was found under ${java_parent_loc}"` and got `Java was found under `. IOW, java_parent_loc was blank?

Comment: Or it was just `/bin/java`

Comment: @ChrisF, can you share the base image you're testing against, so I can validate this answer in the same environment?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, my Dockerfile has `FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 type -a -P java | grep -Eo "(/[^/]+){3}"
```

Comment: This can be shortened to `type -aP java | grep -Eo "(/[^/]+){3}"`